# Read *.XLSX file from HDFS in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, hdfs, xlsx

How is it possible to read xlsx files from HDFS in PySpark? One way is to convert it to csv file, but I have a lot of files and I am looking for other methods.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do that using standard spark libraries. You might want to look into this as an alternative - https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel

Answer (score 1):

You can actually read them directly by using `SparkFiles`:

```
# spark is a SparkSession instance
from pyspark import SparkFiles

spark.sparkContext.addFile('hdfs:///user/bekce/myfile.xlsx')
with open(SparkFiles.get('myfile.xlsx'), 'rb') as handle:
    do_whatever(handle)
```